# pip install -U setuptools fail windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pip, upgrade, setuptools

I just installed Python3.7 and Pycharm on my Windows 10 PC.
I am running pip version 9.0.2

In Pycharm, it says I have version 28.8.0 of setuptools, when I try to upgrade this in Pycharm, which I believe runs the line

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

I get the error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it
> is being used by another process:
> 'c:\users\Username\pycharmprojects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-
> packages\setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg' ->
> 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-i5jxitem-
> uninstall\users\Username\pycharmprojects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-
> packages\setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg'

I have tried running

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

which runs successfully and says I have the latest version.

Does anyone know how I can successfully update setuptools?

The reason I'd like setuptools to be up to date, is so I can then get rid of the egg_info error installing other packages.

Answer (score 50):

I have the same error. Not sure why it happened. But I managed to upgrade by running:
`pip install setuptools --upgrade --ignore-installed`

Comment: To clarify: open a terminal, and run the above command. If you omit the '--ignore-installed', you will get the same error that PyCharm emits.

Comment: Solved it for me when trying to upgrade setuptools from 40.8.0 to 45.0.0

Answer (score 4):

You can also try:

```
easy_install --upgrade setuptools
```

Even though easy_install's deprecated, there's a good chance it'll still work on Windows.

If you try to use pip to upgrade setuptools:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

it seems to get stuck on an error about 10.0 vs 18.0 "You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

The official pip doco(https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip) says on Windows to use this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

However, it seemed pip and setuptools had a hiccup with a circular dependency or lock around pip-v9.0 or 10.0 to pip-18.0 and setuptools v28.0 to v39.0 or 40.0 so persevere with this:

```
python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip
```

You need setuptools >= 39.0 if you want to install pipenv also.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command to upgrade the setup tools in windows

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

or

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved more or less similar problem as follow:

In my `PyCharm` project terminal tab:

```
`(venv) PS C:/path/to/project>`
```

updated `pip, setup tools and wheels` with command:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

([source of recommendation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/))