# pandas installation error using pip installer

Tags: pandas, pip

I am getting following error repeatedly while installing pandas through pip installer for python 3.7 in command prompt

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/fc/d0509d445d2724fbc5f9c9a6fc9ce7da794873469739b6c94afc166ac2a2/pandas-0.23.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 204kB/s
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/68/d87d9b36af36f44254a8d512cbfc48369103a3b9e474be9bdfe536abfc45/python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 187kB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.9.0 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/b5/f4bdf7bce5f8b35a2a83a0b70c545ca061a50b54724b5287505064906b14/numpy-1.16.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (10.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 10.0MB 139kB/s
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-hwub07hg\\29e06807d5aed8dd372ea37c64d1e88dc172ee212d473a412d5e638c'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I have run the command through administrator but it didnt workout.

Comment: try adding the `--no-cache-dir` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade as [Jonny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49479548/10546341) suggested.Restart your computer,Upgrade pip and try installing pandas with [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) or `pip install --user <package_name>`.
Also take a look at [PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215462/permissionerror-winerror-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is).
Hope it was helpful.