# Getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.version' " while having setuptools already installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-10, wmi, setuptools

When trying to run: `pip install -e git+https://github.com/tjguk/wmi.git#egg=wmi`, I got the following error:
[image: cmd output]

Which is a pretty well known problem so when googling the problem I found many relevant threads such as:
[pip install -U setuptools fail windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338652/pip-install-u-setuptools-fail-windows-10)

In which I tried the most voted solution and got the "infamous" message again:
[image: cmd output second try]

I kept looking for a solution until I got to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309412/how-do-i-set-up-setuptools-for-python-2-6-on-windows/309783#309783), which was really comprehensive but unfortunately, somewhat outdated since I'm told to use Python 3.

In the end of the output, logs are mentioned, If I need to attach them here I'll need directions on how to retrieve them and I'll gladly attach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, after looking up the directory:

"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\setuptools"

I found out that it does not contain the module "version.py" which was probably used to check if 'setuptools' was installed.

So I tried to copy the contents of "C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\setuptools"
into the matching folder mentioned above and now the problem is solved, I even tried to restart my PC to see if the fix was temporary - Gladly, it wasn't.

Although I'm not sure why the problem occurred to begin with, it seems to be solved now.

The output after the fix:
[image: fixed output]